# Facebook OAuth with sorcery not saving emails to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, email, oauth, sorcery

Having trouble saving new users to my database through facebook oauth, because I have email set to null: false, and it's not grabbing emails when it tries to authenticate.  Do not want to change my database as a workaround.

```rb
 config.facebook.key = ENV['facebook_app_id']
 config.facebook.secret = ENV['facebook_api_secret']
 config.facebook.callback_url = "http://0.0.0.0:3000/oauth/callback?provider=facebook"
 config.facebook.user_info_mapping = { :email => "email", :name=> "name"}
 config.facebook.user_info_path = "me?fields=email, name"
 config.facebook.scope = "email" #etc
 config.facebook.display = "popup"
 config.facebook.access_permissions = ["email", "user_friends", "public_profile"]
 config.facebook.api_version = "v2.5"
```

users table looks like:

```rb
create_table "users",            force: :cascade do |t|
t.string     "name"
t.text       "about_me"
t.string     "email",            null: false
t.string     "crypted_password"
t.string     "salt"
t.datetime   "created_at"
t.datetime   "updated_at"
# .....
```

server logs:

```
SQL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2016-03-14 00:50:35.548272"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-14 00:50:35.548272"]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Comment: You are user the user have an email address that is verified?

Comment: Yes. Tried with another account as well

Comment: Try do the same query with the same access token in Graph Explorer

Comment: Please give code where user saves to database.
Or users saving occurs inside gem? Them say us what gem that you are use.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  The email column being null => false was screwing it up.  Also, I had done this using the sorcery wiki on external authorization after setting up the basic sorcery auth, and the wiki seems to be deprecated.  My user model and authentication model both had attr_accessor for email, name, etc...which was also screwing it up.  Taking that out and putting authentications with a hash of accessibles in my user controller strong params worked better.

Thanks to everyone who took a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your server log, your work (on controller/ model) not saving `email` attribute into `User` model.

As you declared in migration, `users` have to validate `email` (not allow null) so that `User` cannot be created.

Check around your controller/ model while saving user from Facebook OAuth.

Anyway, in rails, I recommend you using gem `devise` for user and `omniauth-facebook` for Facebook OAuth.